# Symfony deployment problem on hostinger, impossible to download dependencies

Tags: symfony, dependencies, composer-php, hosting

I have been trying for several days to deploy a Symfony site. All the files are well in the public folder with the .htaccess, I only need the dependencies for the site to be functional. The problem is that when I run the command

```
php composer.phar update
```

[image: Serveur ssh error]

I get several error messages concerning my version of PHP.
The host is hostinger. I know the problem comes from the composer.json file and the version of the bundles but I don't know how to solve the problem.

Thanks

[image: composer.json]

Comment: The composer error tells you the issue. Your PHP version is 7.4.32. You need to install/enable and use PHP 8.1+. Just contact Hostinger support and they should help you enable it in your php.ini.

Comment: I don't use Hostinger, but [this might help](https://www.hostinger.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-change-your-php-version) you choose the version you need.

Comment: Okay thank you so much. I have contacted them and await their response. I will keep you informed.

Comment: Why do you need to run `composer update` during deployment? Also, please share all error messages in text form

Comment: I contacted hostinger, and the problem is that the server was in PHP7 after changing to PHP8 it worked. Thank you all for your responses

Answer (score 0):

you need php version 8.1 as the message says. Normally, for a deployment you should not launch a `composer update`. It would rather be a `composer install`.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted hostinger, and the problem is that the server was in PHP7 after changing to PHP8 it worked. Thank you all for your responses